# image in cards bot visible on desktop navigator and on google Chat Android but not in google Chat iOs

Tags: image, google-hangouts, card

Hello and thanks by advance
(sorry for my english)

Please, My bot send cards with pictures (pictures hosted in Drive - with public share).

I never succeeded to make visible the picture with the url of picture.

after searchs I create automatically a new url for each pictures with `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=`  + [id] of picture

And the pictures are visible on cards in navigator desktop, on google Chat Andoid but not on google Chat iOs.

until now I don't no why and nobody could tell me.

I hope this problem will speak to some of you. And that you can will help me

Thanks by advance

Comment: Since your project seems to work on other platforms, I'd say to notify Google about it. On browser the option is on `?` (help) > "Send feedback to Google", I'm not too sure about iOS.

Comment: thank you, it's the google help who adviced me of to talk of my problem here.
But Yes I wil try too of the side of iOs.
Thanks